# Get InnerHTML, OuterHTML, and plain text of an element by ID or class

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I do a fair amount of scraping but I am by no way a good PHP programmer. I always struggle to get the innerhtml of elements using PHP, domdocument and XPath.

I have cobbled together a couple of functions that appear to do what I need but my question is are there any major holes in my logic or how can it be improved.

Disclaimer - I did not write all of the code but the functions below are amalgamations of others code with a little rewriting by myself. If you can easily identify the code as yours please let me know so I can add a credit to you.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$htmlstring = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="testclass" id="attachment_371" style="width: 466px">
    <div>
        <p>This paragraph is in the first child div</p>
    </div>
    <p>This is a standalone paragraph</p>
    <div>
        <span id="attachment_371">Span in a div</span>
        <p>This paragraph is in the second child div</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';


$return = getHTMLElementsByID('attachment_371',$htmlstring,array('div'));
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($return);

/*$return = getHTMLElementsByID('attachment_371',$htmlstring);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($return);

$return = getHTMLElementsByClass('testclass',$htmlstring);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($return);*/


function getHTMLElementsByID($id,$htmlstring,$tags = array('*')) {
    $contents = array();
    $pattern = "/<([\w]+)([^>]*?)(([\s]*\/>)|(>((([^<]*?|<\!\-\-.*?\-\->)|(?R))*)<\/\\1[\s]*>))/sm";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlstring);
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    libxml_clear_errors();
    libxml_use_internal_errors($libxml_previous_state);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($tags as $tagname) {
    $elements = $xpath->query('//'.$tagname.'[@id="'.$id.'"]');
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $elementhtml = $dom->saveXML($element);
            preg_match_all($pattern, $elementhtml, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
                $x = new SimpleXMLElement("<element ".(isset($matches[2][$key][0]) ? $matches[2][$key][0] : '')." />");
                $plaintext = isset($matches[6][$key][0]) ? $matches[6][$key][0] : '';
                $plaintext = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $plaintext);
                $plaintext = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\t","&#13;"), ' ', $plaintext);
                $plaintext = trim(preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $plaintext));
                $contents[] = array(
                    'tagname'    => $matches[1][$key][0],
                    'attributes' => current($x->attributes()),
                    'outer_html' => $match[0],
                    'inner_html' => isset($matches[6][$key][0]) ? $matches[6][$key][0] : '',
                    'plain_text' => $plaintext,
                    'LibXMLError'=> $errors
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $contents;
}

function getHTMLElementsByClass($classname,$htmlstring,$tags = array('*')) {
    $contents = array();
    $pattern = "/<([\w]+)([^>]*?)(([\s]*\/>)|(>((([^<]*?|<\!\-\-.*?\-\->)|(?R))*)<\/\\1[\s]*>))/sm";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlstring);
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    libxml_clear_errors();
    libxml_use_internal_errors($libxml_previous_state);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($tags as $tagname) {
        $elements = $xpath->query('//'.$tagname.'[@class="'.$classname.'"]');
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $elementhtml = $dom->saveXML($element);
            preg_match_all($pattern, $elementhtml, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
                $x = new SimpleXMLElement("<element ".(isset($matches[2][$key][0]) ? $matches[2][$key][0] : '')." />");
                $plaintext = isset($matches[6][$key][0]) ? $matches[6][$key][0] : '';
                $plaintext = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $plaintext);
                $plaintext = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\t","&#13;"), ' ', $plaintext);
                $plaintext = trim(preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $plaintext));
                $contents[] = array(
                    'tagname'    => $matches[1][$key][0],
                    'attributes' => current($x->attributes()),
                    'outer_html' => $match[0],
                    'inner_html' => isset($matches[6][$key][0]) ? $matches[6][$key][0] : '',
                    'plain_text' => $plaintext,
                    'LibXMLError'=> $errors
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $contents;
}



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Except for the difference between `@id=…` and `@class=…` (and an indentation error on that line), the two functions look identical. You should avoid cut-and-paste code by implementing both `getElementsById()` and `getElementsByClass()` in terms of a common helper function — perhaps `getElementsByXPath()`.

In any document, an `id` is supposed to [uniquely identify at most one element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id); having two elements with the same `id` is an error. Therefore, `getElementsById()` should be `getElementById()`, and it should return just the first element it finds (or `NULL` if not found).

> [The `Element.id` property] must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using `getElementById`.

That means that your example HTML is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestions regarding a helper function.  I will look into it.

I understand the point you are making with unique id's but in the real world I am forever coming across code where there are multiple id's with the same value.  I have deliberately allowed for this and of course made the sample html invalid to prove that the multiple elements are returned and included the libxmlerrors to notify me that there are errors in the html.

Comment: When working with valid documents, a `getElementsById()` that returns an array is cumbersome, as it requires you to unpack the one-element array. I'd rather use a generic `getElementsByXPath()` or `getElementsByAttribute()` function when working with a document that I suspect to be non-compliant, so that `getElementById()` returns a single element like it should.